# Stays in while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int iterations, counter;
    double i = -1, j = 3, PI, calculate = 0;

    printf("How many iterations?: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &iterations);
    counter = iterations;

    while (counter > 0) {
        calculate = calculate + (i/j);
        i = i * (-1);
        j += 2;
        counter += -1;
    }

    PI = 4 * (1 + (calculate));
    printf("PI = %f\n", PI);

    return 0;
}
```

This program is in C.
When I run it, it stays in the loop and will not give any output.
If I stop the program it gives the correct result.
What is wrong?

Comment: Time to start the debugger ...

Comment: `counter += -1;` -> `counter -= 1;` -> `counter--;`.  At first I thought you were increasing the variable...

Answer (score 4):

Change the `scanf()` statement

```
scanf("%d\n", &iterations);
```

to this

```
scanf("%d", &iterations);
```

**What difference does it make?**

Putting any whitespace in the `scanf()` format string makes it read and skip over all whitespace in the input. As long as you keep hitting enter (`'\n'`) or space (`' '`), it'll keep reading, until it reaches a non-whitespace character (or `end of file`)

---

Additionally, it'd be good if you also check the return value of `scanf()`

```
if(scanf("%d", &iterations) == 1)
{
    //continue...
}
else
{
    //scan the number again
}
```

or even better, use a loop

```
while(scanf("%d", &iterations) != 1);
```

Comment: @sodejonne2 if you have found the answer helpful, you can consider accepting it :)